# I have tried finding why my rchart plot won't show in shinny, Using rchart2 and library location and lower case letters does not fix it

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I'm new to R and shiny and looking to a make an interactive shiny app that allows the user to switch the plots they chart for the data input using rCharts with D3 visualizations.

I can get all of my code to run in R, however when I try to run it in the shiny app, the code compiles, and the page opens, but no plot shows up.  How can I get the plot to display? I have tried using showOutput() in both the UI and the Server functions, and tried to change the library path, and make sure the library reference is all lower case.

Shiny Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)
library(corrplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(htmltools)
require(rCharts)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rjson)
library(devtools)
options(RCHART_LIB = 'dimple')
options(RCHART_LIB = 'nvd3')
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polychart')
options(RCHART_LIB = 'morris')

ui3 <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Survey Data Analysis"),

  # Sidebar 
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("dataset", "Dataset", 
                c("esoph", "upload my own")),
    conditionalPanel("input.dataset === 'upload my own'",
                     fileInput("datafile", ""), 
                     textInput("datafile_sep", "Field Seperator", value = ",")),
    selectInput("plotType","Plot Type:", 
                c( Histogram = "Histogram", Bar = "Bar", Boxplot = "Boxplot", Scatter = "Scatter")), 
    uiOutput("x"),   
    uiOutput("y"),
    checkboxInput("groups", "Grouping Variable", F),
    uiOutput("group")
  ),
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Data Plots",
               column(9, showOutput("pd3", lib = "dimple")
                      #renderUI("plot1")
               )),
      tabPanel("Data",
               dataTableOutput("dataTable"))
    )
  )
))


server3 <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  require(rCharts)
  options(RCHART_LIB = 'dimple')
  options(RCHART_LIB = 'nvd3')
  options(RCHART_LIB = 'polychart')
  options(RCHART_LIB = 'morris')

  #allows user to input data set or try on test set of data 
  dataset <- reactive({
    datasource <- input$dataset
    if(datasource == "upload my own") {
      inFile <- input$datafile
      if(is.null(inFile)) {
        NULL
      } else {
        read.delim(inFile$datapath, sep = gsub("\\t", "\t", input$datafile_sep, fixed = TRUE))
      }
    } else {
      eval(parse(text = datasource))
    }
  })

    #updates y, dependent variable for 2D plots 
    output$y <- renderUI({ 
      obj<-dataset()    
      var.opts<-c(colnames(obj))
      selectInput("y","Dependent Variable:", var.opts) # uddate UI                  
    }) 

    #updates x, independent variable for plots
    output$x <- renderUI({ 
      obj<-dataset()     
      var.opts<-c(colnames(obj))
      selectInput("x","Independent Variable:", var.opts) # uddate UI                 
    })

    #updates grouping variable for comparing data based on categorical variables such as gender 
    output$group <- renderUI({ 
      obj<-dataset()     
      var.opts<-c(colnames(obj))
      selectInput("group","Grouping Variable: ", var.opts) # uddate UI                 
    })

    #creates a plot object from the data so can create proper d3 plots 
    plot.obj <- reactive({
      plot.list<-list() 
      plot.list$data<- dataset()
      plot.list$x<-as.character(with(plot.list$data, get(input$x)))
      plot.list$freqx <- as.data.frame(table(as.numeric(plot.list$x)))
      colnames(plot.list$freqx) <- (c('x', 'Freq'))
     # if (input$plotType == 'Scatter'){
        plot.list$y<-as.character(with(plot.list$data,get(input$y)))
        plot.list$freqy <- as.data.frame(table(as.numeric(plot.list$y)))
        colnames(plot.list$freqy) <- (c('y', 'Freq'))
        plot.list$variables <- data.frame(as.numeric(plot.list$x), as.numeric(plot.list$y))
        colnames(plot.list$variables) <- (c('x','y'))
      #}
      #if (input$groups == TRUE){
        plot.list$group <- as.character(with(plot.list$data, get(input$group)))
        plot.list$groups = data.frame(as.numeric(plot.list$x), as.numeric(plot.list$group))
        colnames(plot.list$groups) <- (c('x', 'g'))
      #}
      return(plot.list)
    })

    #makes sure correct rcharts library is referenced for each type of plot.  
    rchart_lib <- reactive({
      if (input$plotType == "Histogram"){
        pkg = "dimple"
      }
      if(input$plotType == "Bar" && input$groups == TRUE){
        pkg = "nvd3"
      }
      else{
        pkg = "morris"
      }
      if(input$plotType == "Scatter"){ 
        pkg = "nvd3"
      }
      if(input$plotType == "Boxplot" && input$groups == TRUE){
        pkg = "polychart"
      }

      #pkg = paste("/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rCharts/libraries/", pkg, sep = "")
      pkg = paste("/Users/laurastevens/Library/R/3.1/library/devtools/libs/rCharts/libraries/", pkg, sep = "") 
      return(pkg)
      print(pkg)
    })

    pd3 <- reactive({
      plot.df <- plot.obj()
      if (input$plotType == "Histogram"){
        p = dPlot(Freq~x, data = plot.df$freqx, type = 'bar', xAxis = list(orderRule = "x"), barGap = 0)

      }
      if (input$plotType == "Bar" && input$groups == TRUE){
        p = nPlot(Freq ~ x, group = 'g', data = data.frame(table(plot.df$groups)), type = 'multiBarChart')
      }
      else{
        p = mPlot(x = 'x', y = list('Freq'), data = plot.df$freqx, type = 'Bar', labels = list("Count"))
      }
      if(input$plotType == "Scatter" && input$groups == TRUE){
        p = nPlot(Freq~x, group = 'g', data = data.frame(table(plot.df$groups)), type = 'scatterChart')
      }
      else{
        p = nPlot(x ~ y,  data  = plot.df$variables, type = 'scatterChart')
      }
      if(input$plotType == "Boxplot" && input$groups == TRUE){
        # compute boxplot statistics and cast it as a dataframe with no headers
        dat = data.frame(boxplot(x ~ g, data = plot.df$groups, plot = F)$stats)
        # compute boxplot statistics and cast it as a dataframe with no headers
        bwstats = setNames(
          as.data.frame(dat[complete.cases(dat),]),
          nm = NULL
        )
        #initialize
        p <- Highcharts$new()

        # pass data as a list of lists
        p$set(series = list(list(name = input$group, data = bwstats)))

        # set xaxis/yaxis titles and labels
        p$xAxis(
          categories = levels(plot.df$groups$group),
          title = list(text = input$group)
        )
        p$yAxis(
          title = list(text = input$x)
        )
        p$chart(type = 'boxplot')
      }
      else{
        p = boxplot(as.numeric(plot.df$x), xlab = input$x)
      }
      return(p)
    })

  #creates chart based on p returned from pd3
  output$d3chart1 <- renderChart({
     p1 <- pd3()
     p1$addparams(height = 600, dom = "pd3")
     return(p1)
   })

  #connects shinyUI and shinyServer functions for plot
  output$plot1 <- renderUI({
    if(input$plotType == "Boxplot" && input$groups == FALSE){
       plotOutput("d3Chart1")
    }
    else{
      rc_lib <- rchart_lib()
      showOutput("d3Chart1", rc_lib)
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui3, server = server3)
```

I am using R 3.3.1: 
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] corrplot_0.77        stringr_1.1.0        sqldf_0.4-10         RSQLite_1.0.0        DBI_0.5-1
 [6] gsubfn_0.6-6         proto_1.0.0          XLConnect_0.2-12     XLConnectJars_0.2-12 devtools_1.12.0
[11] rjson_0.2.15         dplyr_0.5.0          plyr_1.8.4           rCharts_0.4.5        htmltools_0.3.5
[16] markdown_0.7.7       shiny_0.14.2         ROCR_1.0-7           gplots_3.0.1         ggplot2_2.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7        bitops_1.0-6       tools_3.3.1        digest_0.6.10      jsonlite_1.1       memoise_1.0.0
 [7] tibble_1.2         gtable_0.2.0       lattice_0.20-33    yaml_2.1.13        gridExtra_2.2.1    rJava_0.9-8
[13] withr_1.0.2        gtools_3.5.0       caTools_1.17.1     grid_3.3.1         data.table_1.9.6   R6_2.2.0
[19] RJSONIO_1.3-0      gdata_2.17.0       whisker_0.3-2      magrittr_1.5       scales_0.4.0       assertthat_0.1
[25] mime_0.5           xtable_1.8-2       colorspace_1.2-7   httpuv_1.3.3       KernSmooth_2.23-15 stringi_1.1.1